# Pry show-source not showing implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rdoc, pry, ri

Using Pry `show-source` it's not showing me the method implementation as I expected:

```
[2] pry(main)> show-source Object#extend

From: eval.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 3

static VALUE
rb_obj_extend(argc, argv, obj)
int argc;
```

That's all I get, but according to the [official docs](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Source-browsing#C_source) (I have pry-doc installed) I should see:

```
[1] pry(main)> show-source Object#extend

From: eval.c (C Method):
Owner: Kernel
Visibility: public
Number of lines: 16

static VALUE
rb_obj_extend(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE obj)
{
    int i;

    if (argc == 0) {
         rb_raise(rb_eArgError, "wrong number of arguments (at least 1)");
    }
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    Check_Type(argv[i], T_MODULE);
    while (argc--) {
        rb_funcall(argv[argc], rb_intern("extend_object"), 1, obj);
        rb_funcall(argv[argc], rb_intern("extended"), 1, obj);
    }
    return obj;
}
[2] pry(main)>
```

Any ideas about why is this happening?

Comment: It's not a bug, it's expected behaviour. How you expect for Ruby to show C code from compiled binary?

Comment: From the official documentation: "When the  pry-doc plugin is installed (gem install pry-doc) the C source for Ruby core methods (MRI) become available."

Comment: Sorry, I must have misread that.

Comment: pry-doc holds source code for methods that are written in C, so when you look up one of them you get source from this gem, since it's not possible to decompile it from Ruby.

Comment: And if you don't understand what I just wrote I think you should make yourself familiar with C programming language a little.

Comment: I understand that, but my question is given that I'm using the pry-doc gem, why it's not showing the source? as it's suppose to. It's not about decompiling C code to see the implementation.

Comment: From https://github.com/pry/pry-doc "Pry Doc is also smart enough to get any documentation for methods and classes implemented in C." and "Pry Doc supports the following Rubies: ·MRI 2.1" which is what I'm using.

Comment: Also "Pry Doc extends two core Pry commands: show-doc and show-source (aliased as ? and $ respectively).". In my case show-doc it's working properly but not show-source.

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

`$ rvm docs generate all`

Also useful, if you want to generate the ri docs for all your installed gems:

`gem rdoc --all --ri --no-rdoc`